# displaying image with name in android

Tags: android, image

Hi Here I am going to displaying image with text.for that this is my code.If i run this application it showing log cat errors.

for eg:a.jpeg with name a like this i want.

But it's giving unfortunately error.

can anyone please help me

**Photos class**

```
public class Photos extends Activity {

    Button button1;  
    String mImages;

      public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.photos);

        ViewPager viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.view_pager);
        ImagePagerAdapter adapter = new ImagePagerAdapter();
        viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
      }

      private class ImagePagerAdapter extends PagerAdapter {
       private int[] mImages = new int[] {        
            R.drawable.a,
            R.drawable.b,
            R.drawable.c,
            R.drawable.d  
        };
          String[] description_images = getIntent().getExtras().getStringArray("[{image1,image2,image3,image4}]"); //ARRAY OF ALL TEXT ASSOCIATED TO IMAGES
         // String[] mImages1 = getIntent().getExtras().getStringArray("mImages");  


       // String[] mText={"Text1","Text2","Text3"};

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
          return mImages.length;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean isViewFromObject(View view, Object object) {
          return view == ((ImageView) object);
        }

        @Override
        public View instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, int position) {
            LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(container.getContext());
            View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.image_view, null);
            final ImageView imageView = (ImageView)view.findViewById(R.id.iv_image);
            final TextView textView = (TextView )view.findViewById(R.id.iv_text);

            textView.setText(description_images[position]);
           imageView.setImageResource(mImages[position]);
            container.addView(view, 0);
            return view;
        }

        @Override
        public void destroyItem(ViewGroup container, int position, Object object) {
            container.removeView((View) object);
        }
    }
}
```

**logcat error**

```
07-17 16:37:11.391: E/AndroidRuntime(562): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
07-17 16:37:11.391: E/AndroidRuntime(562): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.imagegallery/com.example.imagegallery.Photos}: java.lang.NullPointerException
07-17 16:37:11.391: E/AndroidRuntime(562):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2663)
07-17 16:37:11.391: E/AndroidRuntime(562):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2679)
07-17 16:37:11.391: E/AndroidRuntime(562):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2300(ActivityThread.java:125)
07-17 16:37:11.391: E/AndroidRuntime(562):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2033)
07-17 16:37:11.391: E/AndroidRuntime(562):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
07-17 16:37:11.391: E/AndroidRuntime(562):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
07-17 16:37:11.391: E/AndroidRuntime(562):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
07-17 16:37:11.391: E/AndroidRuntime(562):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-17 16:37:11.391: E/AndroidRuntime(562):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
07-17 16:37:11.391: E/AndroidRuntime(562):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
07-17 16:37:11.391: E/AndroidRuntime(562):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
07-17 16:37:11.391: E/AndroidRuntime(562):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
07-17 16:37:11.391: E/AndroidRuntime(562): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
07-17 16:37:11.391: E/AndroidRuntime(562):  at com.example.imagegallery.Photos$ImagePagerAdapter.<init>(Photos.java:36)
07-17 16:37:11.391: E/AndroidRuntime(562):  at com.example.imagegallery.Photos$ImagePagerAdapter.<init>(Photos.java:29)
07-17 16:37:11.391: E/AndroidRuntime(562):  at com.example.imagegallery.Photos.onCreate(Photos.java:25)
07-17 16:37:11.391: E/AndroidRuntime(562):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
07-17 16:37:11.391: E/AndroidRuntime(562):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2627)
07-17 16:37:11.391: E/AndroidRuntime(562):  ... 11 more
```

Comment: `I am going to displaying image with text.` Sorry I have no idea what you want. Please explain first.

Comment: why are you declaring the button if you are not using it

Comment: Are you passing `[{image1,image2,image3,image4}]` in the `Intent` from the previous `Activity`?

Comment: From the log, it says the error happened at line 36? but , which line is the 36 ?

Comment: this is only one java file

Comment: i want to displaying image with name for that i took one string arraylist with images and text now i want to display the image and down i want with name

Comment: You are only repeating yourself. You clarify none of our remarks. You didn't answer questions.

Comment: I am new to android please tell me

Comment: Instead of String[] description_images = getIntent().getExtras().getStringArray("[{image1,image2,image3,image4}]"); this line, use this String[] description_images = new String[]{"text u want", "text u want", "text u want", "text u want"};

Comment: hi RIT then also same errors